# Check input of form field - if postcode exists, alert javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, alert, indexof

Need to append a script to a text field in an 'enter postcode' field, which will actively check the content and pop up an alert. Blacklisting postcodes, basically.

Here is what I have:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="20" size="25" value="" name="zipc" id="zipc">
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery("#zipc").ready(function () {
    function BFPO(t) {
        if (t.value.match(/\"BF1 3AA"/g)) {
            alert('We cannot send parcels to BFPO addresses. Ever.');
            t.value = t.value.replace(/\s/g,'');
        }
    }
});
```

Now, I'm aware that is doesn't work but how do I fully 'ready' an alert like this when you then select the next field to type in? Perhaps the use of **indexOf()**?

Any help would be great and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the solution, if anyone was wondering:

```
jQuery('#zipc').focusout(function () {
var _val = jQuery(this).val();
var _array = ["BF1 3AA", "Some_postcode"];
for (var i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
    if (_val.indexOf(_array[i]) != -1) {
        alert('OH, snap! That\'s a BFPO postcode... We don\'t send stuff there. Bummer.');
           jQuery('#zipc').val("");
    }
}});
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/WbDpG/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use focusout function. check this out

[Focusout jquery](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

and also you can use
blur() function as well

```
$('#textfieldid').blur(function() {
  //logic
});
```

Comment: Perhaps something like this instead, Thuiya?

`jQuery("#zipc").focusout(function () {
       if (t.value.match(/\"BF1 3AA"/g)) {
    alert('We cannot send parcels to BFPO addresses. Ever.');
    t.value = t.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
}
});`